# useState to set iterated data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to do some plotting, which requires the data to presented in a certain way, i.e.:

```
[{
    type: "box",
    y: data[1],
    name: "1",
    boxpoints: "all",
  },
  {
    type: "box",
    y: data[2],
    name: "2",
    boxpoints: "all",
  },
   {
    type: "box",
    y: data[3],
    name: "3",
    boxpoints: "all",
}]
```

My data is set somewhere else via the `useState` hook:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([])
```

And now I would like to set another `useState`, which contains the above, i.e. the manual way would be to just do:

```
const [plotData, setPlotData] = useState([])

setPlotData([{
    type: "box",
    y: data[1],
    name: "1",
    boxpoints: "all",
  },
  {
    type: "box",
    y: data[2],
    name: "2",
    boxpoints: "all",
  },
   {
    type: "box",
    y: data[3],
    name: "3",
    boxpoints: "all",
}])
```

And then everything works. The problem is that I don't know in advance the length of the `data`. So in this case I know it's 3, and can do it manually, but it could be another value. Therefore I would like to iterate through it, also to keep the code more clean.

But I am unsure how I actually create this iteration/list of dictionaries on a `useState`.

Comment: Where is this data coming from? Why not initialize the `data` state with it instead of an empty array? Or are you asking how to "copy", or map, the `data` state into the `plotData` state?

Comment: You can use `data.map()` to create a new array with the correct shape from the values in `data`.

Comment: For the first element of the array, you can use the following statement to read the length of `data` 

`plotData[0].y.length`

and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect use for the [memo hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) which can create a computed value based on state dependencies.

```js
const plotData = useMemo(
  () =>
    data.slice(1).map((y, i) => ({
      y,
      name: (i + 1).toString(),
      type: "box",
      breakpoints: "all",
    })),
  [data]
);
```

The use of [`data.slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) is because you seemed to want to skip the first entry in `data` based on your examples.